# Use opt/ cmd + Backspace in tkinter

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I have a very simple notepad that is made out of the `tk.text` widget.

The only thing lacking is OPT/ CMD + Backspace support on Mac (deleting lines and words).

Any way i could add support for it? either through tkinter directly or though a selfmade function?

EDIT: I also found out that navigating text using OPT and the arrow keys work, why it doesnt work in combination with Backspace i dont know.

Comment: Do you know how to use the `bind` command? There's nothing special you need to do, you can bind a function to just about any keystroke you want. It's not really clear what you're having a problem with since `bind` is documented and there are countless examples on the internet.

Comment: @BryanOakley i know how it works. What i want to find out if theres a tkinter-made solution. Some attribute that i hat to set to `True`. In case there is nothing left im going to use .bind

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimum reproducable example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @D.L there is no code. Its simply a question about the tkinter object `tk.text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, there are modifier keys that bound to Mac keys([source](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/bind.htm)):

> The Command and Option modifiers are equivalents of Mod1 resp. Mod2, they correspond to Macintosh-specific modifier keys.

this means that if you want to use CMD/ OPT on Mac you can use `Mod1` & `Mod2` like any other key:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

root = tkinter.Tk()

def func(event):
    entry.insert(string="hello",index=0)

entry = ttk.Entry(root)
entry.bind("<Mod2-Return>",func) 
#if you press OPT+Enter Key, hello gets inserted
entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```